# C# Reading json and edit

Tags: c#, json

**SOLUTION**

```
        Profile newProfileList = new Profile();
        newProfileList = myDeserializedClass.profiles[0]; // New profile list is null so i've casted some values from old ones.
        myDeserializedClass.profiles.Add(newProfileList);
        richTextBox1.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDeserializedClass);
```

Then i can save it as json file again. Thanks to @Donut

I've got the following code:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
string txtProfile;
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtProfile = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
    richTextBox1.Text = txtProfile;
}
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(richTextBox1.Text);
```

Using this code, I'm able to read a JSON file and deserialize it successfully to an instance of the `Root` class. However, when I try to create new profiles in this object, I get some error about "read only values":

> Form1.cs(124,13,124,47): error CS0200: Property or indexer 'List<Form1.Profile>.Count' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

How can I correctly edit the deserialized data (e.g. add new instances of the `Profile` class), and save it back to the JSON file?

For reference, here are the classes I'm using for deserialization.

```
public class Metadata
{
    public string app_flavor { get; set; }
    public int app_version { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int ajax_connections_limit { get; set; }
    public bool allow_emulator_ua_detection { get; set; }
    public string apply_css_patches { get; set; }
    public bool created_by_user { get; set; }
    public string custom_user_agent { get; set; }
    public bool device_custom_dev_id2 { get; set; }
    public string device_id { get; set; }
    public string device_id2 { get; set; }
    public string device_id_seed { get; set; }
    public string device_signature { get; set; }
    public string display_resolution { get; set; }
    public bool enable_ministra_compatibility { get; set; }
    public bool external_player_send_back_key_event { get; set; }
    public bool external_player_send_exit_key_event { get; set; }
    public bool external_player_send_key_event { get; set; }
    public bool external_player_send_ok_key_event { get; set; }
    public string firmware { get; set; }
    public string firmware_js_api_ver { get; set; }
    public string firmware_player_engine_ver { get; set; }
    public string firmware_stb_api_ver { get; set; }
    public bool fix_ajax { get; set; }
    public bool fix_background_color { get; set; }
    public bool fix_local_file_scheme { get; set; }
    public bool front_panel { get; set; }
    public int generic_connections_limit { get; set; }
    public string hardware_vendor { get; set; }
    public string hardware_version { get; set; }
    public string image_date { get; set; }
    public string image_description { get; set; }
    public string image_version { get; set; }
    public string internal_portal_url { get; set; }
    public bool is_internal_portal { get; set; }
    public int lang_audiotracks { get; set; }
    public int lang_subtitles { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public bool limit_max_connections { get; set; }
    public string mac_address { get; set; }
    public string mac_seed_net_interface { get; set; }
    public string media_player { get; set; }
    public bool media_player_per_channel { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string ntp_server { get; set; }
    public string overwrite_stream_protocol { get; set; }
    public string playlist_charset { get; set; }
    public string portal_url { get; set; }
    public string proxy_host { get; set; }
    public int proxy_port { get; set; }
    public bool send_device_id { get; set; }
    public string serial_number { get; set; }
    public bool show_player_name { get; set; }
    public string stb_internal_config { get; set; }
    public string stb_model { get; set; }
    public bool subtitles_on { get; set; }
    public string tasks_data { get; set; }
    public bool timeshift_enabled { get; set; }
    public string timeshift_path { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public bool udpxy_enabled { get; set; }
    public string udpxy_url { get; set; }
    public bool use_alt_stalker_auth_dialog { get; set; }
    public bool use_alternative_web_view_scale_method { get; set; }
    public bool use_browser_redirection { get; set; }
    public bool use_custom_user_agent { get; set; }
    public bool use_extended_mag_api { get; set; }
    public bool use_http_proxy { get; set; }
    public bool use_mac_based_device_id { get; set; }
    public string user_agent { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string video_resolution { get; set; }
    public int video_resume_time { get; set; }
    public string weather_place { get; set; }
    public bool web_proxy_enabled { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> profiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only read only property is the `Count` property of `profiles`, because it's a `List<Profile>`. To change the `Count`, you have to add or remove items from the list.

Comment: @HereticMonkey how can i do that? Can you give me specific example or keywords to me for how i'm gonna cast new List<Profile> ?

Comment: You can just call `profiles.Add(new Profile() ...)`. Adding to or removing items from the list will update the `Count` property automatically... but based on what it sounds like you're trying to do, the `Count` property isn't really necessary to serialize the object back to JSON.

Comment: It's not clear where in the code you're getting the error. You can [see from the documentation of `List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) there is an `Add` method which will add items to a list...

Comment: myDeserializedClass.profiles.Add(new Profile() ...)

Comment: Oh thanks for everyone nad especially Donut! Now i'm able to create new count in profile section of json by using myDeserializedClass.profiles.Add(new Profile()); and i'm able to serialize it again. Thanks for everyone